# Liquibase multiple classpath

Tags: windows, classpath, liquibase

I am just trying to execute liquibase update from command line but can't find any way to pass multiple paths for `--classpath` parameter. I am using command as follow:

```
liquibase.bat \
      --driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver \
      --classpath="C:/Users/Me/path_to_driver/ojdbc7.jar" \
      --changeLogFile="C:/Users/Me/path_to_changelog_file/changelog.xml" \
      --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@db_host:1521:xe" \
      --username=user_name \
      --password=some_pass \
      update
```

It is possible to add one path more to `--classpath`? I need to add path to changeSet files and I'm using Windows.

Comment: for what do you need classpath? what is inside your liquibase.bat? If you are executing some kind of java program then try to use `java -cp <your classpath> liquibase.integration.commandline.Main [parameters]`

Comment: From help:  `--classpath=<value>                        Classpath migration files and JDBC Driver`. How to point to ojdbc jar and changeset directory at once?

Comment: did you tried to use `;` as a classpath separator?

Comment: If i use syntax like `"some_path;C:/Users/username/path_to_ojdbc/ojdbc7.jar"` then i get: `Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unexpected value C:/Users/username/path_to_ojdbc/ojdbc7.jar: parameters must start with a '--'`.

If i use syntax like `"some_path";"C:/Users/username/path_to_ojdbc/ojdbc7.jar"` then i get sth like:
    `ojdbc7.jar: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found
    ojdbc7.jar: line 2: ▒^▒D: command not found
    ojdbc7.jar: line 44: syntax error near unexpected token `$'▒k▒\034z"\t▒I▒0▒▒Y...`

Comment: Ok I think `--classpath` is meant to be only jdbc driver or `war|ear|jar` which contains jdbc driver and also migration files (maybe if you look into source code you will find more). But you can do what I suggested in first comment - put your changelogs to system classpath `java -cp <classpath>` and put jdbcdriver to `--classpath`. Parameter `--includeSystemClasspath` should do the trick because it will load changelogs from system classpath.

Answer (score 3):

`--classpath=path:anotherPath` should work

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage on windows systems is

```
--classpath="C:\repository1\;D:\repository2\;D:/"
```

please note the third path is *base root*, which is useful in liquibase 4.0+ for backward compatibility

(*"Specifying files by absolute path was removed in Liquibase 4.0. Please use a relative path or add '/' to the classpath parameter."*)